# RancherOS default password?

Tags: linux, installation

So I installed RancherOS to disk from ISO. This ISO previously had auto-login set up by default. I proceeded to then remove the ISO and boot to the disk. The problem I ran into is that there is no way to login.

For some reason they did not find reason to document this but according to issues on RancherOS's public repo they say that just using rancher and then entering nothing will work. It doesnt. The password I set during install from ISO does not work either.

What am I supposed to do here? No default password is mentioned anywhere but GitHub issues.

The only thing I keep hearing is to set it up to autlogin by default when you instal it from the ISO but that I can not believe that would be best practice.

They also recomend setting SSH private keys so you can get back in but that still would not help because setting the password of a user requires the user's previous password. And both of these definitely do not help me now anyway since I am already installed.

Answer (score 1):

Citing from the [RancherOS webpage](https://rancher.com/docs/os/v1.x/en/installation/running-rancheros/workstation/boot-from-iso/).
As you said, upon first boot from ISO there is an auto-login:

> If you boot with the ISO, you will automatically be logged in as the rancher user. Only the ISO is set to use autologin by default. If you run from a cloud or install to disk, SSH keys or a password of your choice is expected to be used.

If you then continue with installing RancherOS to disk, the procedure is outlined [here](https://rancher.com/docs/os/v1.x/en/installation/running-rancheros/server/install-to-disk/), [here](https://rancher.com/docs/os/v1.x/en/installation/configuration/#cloud-config) and [here](https://help.github.com/en/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh).

> After installing RancherOS to disk, you will no longer be automatically logged in as the rancher user. You’ll need to have added in SSH keys within your cloud-config file.

Answer (score 0):

On Rancher OS raspi image you can login with :

- login : rancher
- password : rancher

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to install RancherOS with auto-login on tty1.

When you've booted the ISO image, you generally want to install RancherOS with `ros` command. There is an undocumented option to pass:

```
# replace -d /dev/X by the device you want to target
sudo ros install -d /dev/X -a rancher.autologin=tty1
```

That option is not documented but I've seen the kernel options here: https://github.com/rancher/os/blob/master/scripts/isolinux_label.cfg

`ros` command says that you can use `-a` option to add parameters.